# Confidence interval for proportion differences in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am looking for a quick method (without creating too many new dataframes) for the following:

Imagine I have two variables: `data$occupation` (rows, from top to bottom, "1" to "4"), and `data$disease` (columns, from left to right, "yes" and "no") with the following data:

```
mat1<-matrix(c(54,23,28,45,16,10,17,13), 4,2)
```

I would like to end up with a table with proportions of "yes" in the different categories of "occupation", percentage difference in proportions between occupations and the confidence interval of this difference:

with `prop.test(table(data$occupation, data$disease), correct=FALSE)`, I get the different proportions, but now I would like to find a commando which is giving the difference between proportions (with I reference I can enter) with related CI.

Something like `twoby2()` (which gives OR and RR), would be nice.

Comment: Could you not simply bootstrap?  Alternatively, could you not fit a multinominal logit, and get confidence intervals on your linear combinations of coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie in statistics, however, with regards to [this posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60073/confidence-interval-for-difference-between-proportions), I'd try it like this

```
tab <- table(data$occupation, data$disease)
combinations <- t(combn(nrow(tab), 2))
cbind(combinations, t(apply(combinations, 1, function(rows) {
  re <- prop.test(x=tab[rows, 1], n=rep(nrow(data), 2), correct=F)
  re$estimate <- unname(re$estimate)
  return(c(
    propY1 = re$estimate[1], 
    propY2 = re$estimate[2],
    diff = re$estimate[1]-re$estimate[2], 
    l = re$conf.int[1],
    u = re$conf.int[2]
  ))
})))
#             propY1    propY2        diff           l           u
# [1,] 1 2 0.2621359 0.1116505  0.15048544  0.07661756  0.22435331
# [2,] 1 3 0.2621359 0.1359223  0.12621359  0.05007540  0.20235179
# [3,] 1 4 0.2621359 0.2184466  0.04368932 -0.03871570  0.12609434
# [4,] 2 3 0.1116505 0.1359223 -0.02427184 -0.08783067  0.03928698
# [5,] 2 4 0.1116505 0.2184466 -0.10679612 -0.17774178 -0.03585045
# [6,] 3 4 0.1359223 0.2184466 -0.08252427 -0.15583081 -0.00921773
```

Comment: Interesting! If this could work, it would be very very helpful. When I tried it, it gives `Error in apply(rows, 1, function(rows) { : object 'rows' not found`

Comment: Oops, I made a typo. Please try again. Yet, it's still open if this is a valid procedure from a statistical point of view.

Comment: There is new error now `Error in prop.test(x = tab[rows, 1], n = rep(nrow(data), 2), correct = F) : 
  'x' and 'n' must have the same length` If I would get the same results as in `prop.test()` for the individual comparisions, I guess I am good to go, no? By the way, I am only using this for exploratory data analysis

Comment: I used `mat1<-matrix(c(54,23,28,45,16,10,17,13), 4,2, dimnames=list(occupation=vector(), disease=c("yes", "no"))); data <- reshape2::melt(transform(as.data.frame(mat1), occupation=factor(1:4)), id.var="occupation", variable.name="disease"); data <- as.data.frame(splitstackshape::expandRows(data, "value"))` to prepare `data` from your `mat1`.

Comment: Could you reproduce the same thing using a command with the two database variables: for instance the table we need is `tab<-with(data,table(occupation, disease))` Maybe there is something you did differently during this preparation step. So if possible could you present the same steps yet starting with this `tab`?

Comment: By the way, I repeated the code, and now I get: `Error in prop.test(x = tab[rows, 1], n = rep(nrow(data), 2), correct = F) : 
  elements of 'x' must not be greater than those of 'n'`

Comment: `mat1`, as I used it above, equals your `tab`. I cannot reproduce the error, sorry. It runs fine here with the code 3 comments above. .